# HTMLPane missing scrollbar when using FireFox

Tags: html, css, gwt, smartgwt

I'm using HTMLPane to output the html code. (smartgwt 3.0)

I found an issue when an image included in the html code.

This issue only happened with FF, and it can't be reproduced every time.

It seems that the FF can't produce the scroolbar fine.

expect:

[image]

sometimes :

[image]

HTML content :

```
<table width='100%' height='100%' cellspacing='0'><tr><td valign='top' style='padding: 
8px;' class='HTMLPane''><div style='width:483px;'><div class='resize-cnt' 
id="containerId">@<br />
@<br />
@<br />
@<br />
@<br />
@<br />
@<br />
<br />
<br /></div><hr /><div class='resize-pic' align='center'><img
src='/fileIo.service?fileId=18a0989b-f10f-431b-b0cd-e498cec771d8&    
messageId=X2Y4Yzg3ZTgyLTk3Y2UtNDk3NC04M2U2LWZmODQ0MjVkYWM0Ni5yb290QDE4OS43Ni5jb21f'   
title='
xx.png' /></div>
</div></td></tr></table>


.resize-pic img { 
vertical-align: middle; 
max-width:100%;   /* FF IE7 */
max-height:100%; /* FF IE7 */
_width:expression(this.width > 800 && this.width > this.height ? 800: auto); 
_height:expression(this.height > 800 ? 800 : auto); /* IE6 */ 
}

.resize-cnt img { 
max-width:100%;   /* FF IE7 */
max-height:100%; /* FF IE7 */
}
```

My Image is from a servlet. So i can't determine the width and height when giving the html code.

The question is how can scroolbar not missing when needed.

Answer (score 0):

How about using a [scrollPanel](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/ScrollPanel.html) with a HTMLPanel in it ? This might help you avoid CSS quirks and tricks.